# Extract data from CommVault, Netbackup and EMC Data Domain

Tags: backup, data-migration, fileserver, backup-strategies

I want to create a web application where I can extract the data from CommVault, NetBackup and Data Domain Backups and insert them into a thrid backup client such as Rubrik. Is there any way I can do that using a program? Are there API's available for this?
It seems all these providers provide GUI based services and none exposed as code. I did find CommVault SDK which can enable me to browse contents and possibly save data. It would be great help if there could be pointers to others.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but from what I remember Netbackup uses Sybase for it's database to track jobs. I think the trick is finding the right drivers to access it since the regular ones don't work.

I've seen old code where people extracted data from there and combined it with data from the msdb database on SQL for a complete backup report but you'll have to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the actual Backup Data (e.g. files backed up, VMs backup up, etc) to move to Rubric?  Or are you looking for the Meta-Data which are the records of backup jobs and what was backed up and still stored by the backup servers?

If you want the meta-data for reporting, then each backup product is unique, as you have surmised.  There are reporting products out there, such as Bocada, that mine the meta-data from Commvault, NBU, and EMC Data Domain and store it in an open SQL Server DB for reporting.  You could back up that DB with Rubric.

If you are looking to move the actual backed up data, sorry I cannot help with an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

what do you need exactly?

If you running CommVault and you have protected data, you still need at least one CommCell, one media-agent and of course the storage media. You cannot migrate from one backup-tool to another. For Netbackup im sure it's the same. But, for CommVault i can say that you don't need license the environment for restores.

With CommVault, you can also use the "External Data Connector" (https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=40869.htm) for extract Data from external Backup-Tools.

For meta-data extraction you need to use the associated database-engine for each Backup-Tool. But be careful, its not easy - you need to do few days of reverse engineering and i think there is not much documented. (For CommVault here is a short table description: https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=97017.htm )

For Example:

CommVault uses MS-SQL, the installation user has full access to databases

Netapp uses Sybase